# Cross join in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a QuerySet and I need to cross join it with values list, like this

```
SELECT table_name.*, v.flag
FROM table_name
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (FALSE), (TRUE)) AS v(flag)
```

QuerySet is already initialized at this moment, so I cannot use `raw` method, and it is being processed further, so I need QuerySet instance in result. Is there some kind of solution to do this by using only Django ORM tools?

Comment: Umm... not sure, but isn't this roughly the equivalent of `your_model.objects.all().annotate(flag=False).union(your_model.objects.all().annotate(flag=True)` ?

Comment: `union` blocks most of QuerySet methods from using, so yes it's equivalent, but I cannot use `union` in my case

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean by blocks?

Comment: According to the documentation "only LIMIT, OFFSET, COUNT(*), ORDER BY, and specifying columns (i.e. slicing, count(), order_by(), and values()/values_list()) are allowed on the resulting QuerySet" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#union

Comment: Ahh... yes... okay.. could still apply whatever else to each component part I guess